# I download the program python on my windows for the first time

Tags: python-3.x

I downloaded the python of the homepage when I open it it keeps taking me to the Play Store and asking if what app do I want to open the program with, my computer application is in Windows 10 . anybody have the same problem? I cannot open that type of Anaconda

Comment: could you post the exact filename, with file extension?

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to install python in windows,  you can navigate to https://www.python.org/ > `Downloads` > `Download for Windows`

It will download the **python.exe** file which you can use to install.
Double click on the exe file, and you will see the python basic editor.